# mkfs.ext2 in cygwin not working

Tags: windows, filesystems, cygwin, ext2

I'm attempting to create a fs within a file.

under linux it's very simple:

create a blank file size 8 gb

> dd of=fsFile bs=1 count=0 seek=8G

"format" the drive:

> mkfs.ext2 fsFile
>   works great.

however under cygwin running from /usr/sbin ./mkfs.ext2
has all kinds of weird errors (i assume because of some abstraction)

But with cygwin i get:

> mkfs.ext2: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
>           partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
>           a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
>           to re-read your partition table.

or even worse (if i try to access a file through /cygdrive/...

> mkfs.ext2: Bad file descriptor while trying to determine filesystem size

:(
please help,
Thanks

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on ServerFault

Comment: Agree with @gruntled, but also you might want to check and make sure your dd command did what you expected, and modify it if not.

Comment: the problem isn't dd even if i manually create a file with random data in it (making sure there aren't any holes) it doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like it could be 32-bit wraparound, where 8GB would become 0. Have you tried it with something smaller than 4GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that the way to solve it is to not use any path on the file you wish to modify.
doing that seems to have solved it.

also it seems that my 8 gig file does have a file size that's simply to big, it seems like it resets the size var i.e.

> $ /usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 -f testFile8GiG
>   e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
>   The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 2097152 blocks
>   The physical size of the device is 0 blocks
>   Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
>   Abort? no
>   Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
>   Pass 2: Checking directory structure
>   Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
>   Pass 4: Checking reference counts
>   Pass 5: Checking group summary information
>   testFile8GiG: 122/524288 files (61.5% non-contiguous), 253313/2097152 blocks

Thanks anyway